# form submitted with wrong action

Tags: javascript, forms

My form is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
method1(){form.action='first'} 
method2(){form.action='second'}</script>


<form if="formID">
<s:submit onclick="method1();" name="upload"/>
<s:textfield name="search" />
<s:submit onclick="method2()"/>
```

When i press enter key form is submitting with action 'first' . The control is directly going to method1 and submitting. When i press enter key i want control has to go to method2 and form should submit with action 'second'.

How do i can do it?

Comment: what is that language? It is not seems to be html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect which key has been hit.

```
<s:submit onkeypress="return method2(event)"/>

<script>
function method2(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        form.action='second';
        form.submit();
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Or you can use 2 forms, with 2 different submit buttons. But I guess you have more fields that in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks to all :) Its working fine. From more than 2 hours I was trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should have only one submit button per form. If you want method2() to call for enter key, you may do a tweak like as, Define first submit as button and leave second submit as submit.